# Check if a dictionary has any key beyond a certain key (i.e., 1+ keys, not counting a particular key)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Subject should say most. Here's an example:

Suppose I want to know if a given dictionary has any keys, but not counting the key 'one'. So

```
dict = {'one': 1, 'two':2, 'three':3}
```

would return TRUE

```
dict = {'one':1}
```

would return FALSE

```
dict = {'two': 2}
```

would return TRUE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it more or less as your question title suggests: check if it has more than one key, or doesn't have `'one`' as one of its keys:

```
 if len(myDict) > 1 or (len(myDict)==1 and 'one' not in myDict):
```

Comment: Thanks! The only downside is that it would return true for an empty dictionary. But this is easy to fix by adding another condition.

Comment: @Craig: You're right, I edited my answer to handle that case.

Answer (score 3):

`dict.viewkeys` gives you all the keys in a form that behaves like a set (its a backport of how `dict.keys` behaves in python 3). This means you can do this as a set difference:

```
if mydict.viewkeys() - {'one'}:
    # has other keys
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is my solution:

```
if len(mydict) - ('one' in mydict):
    # Your code here
```

With this:

```
mydict = {'one': 1, 'two':2, 'three':3}  # Will return 3 - 1 which is True

mydict = {'one':1}  # Will return 1 - 1 which is False

mydict = {'two': 2}  # Will return 1 - 0 which is True
```

Basically, it will always return the actual length, minus one if `'one'` (or anything else you fancy for that matter) is in the list.

An alternative solution:

```
if len([x for x in mydict if x != 'one']):  # Filters out 'one' if present
    # Your code here
```

Should work pretty well too. I didn't do any benchmarks to compare both solutions though.

Comment: >implying I understood the question the right way. :)

Comment: This is very clever, but not sure it would work if values aren't integers (they are lists of lists in the real code, the example above was just to simplify).

Comment: @Craig Not sure what you mean and how it would fail. I'd be interested to know. :)

Comment: I just tested it -- I was wrong, it does work! I thought you were using the fact that my example had convenient integers... nice solution

Comment: @Craig I prefer my solution at the BrenBarn one (sorry), so I wouldn't mind becoming the selected answer but it is up to you. :D I'll stop chit chat here before SO complains that the comments aren't meant to do so. Have a good day. Glad if I helped.